# Java out-of-bounds error

Tags: java, error-handling, runtime-error

I keep getting an out of bounds error. I want to check for duplicates. There is more after this, but for right now all thats important it says that I'm getting an `OutOfBoundsException` with the `ArrayList`, index:1 size:1

```
ArrayList lottery = new ArrayList();

for (int n = 0; n < 4;) {
    int number = 0;
    int first = 0;
    int value = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    first = (int) (Math.random() * 42 + 1);
    lottery.add(first);
    count[first]++;

    for (int i = 1; i < 6;) {
        number = (int) (Math.random() * 42 + 1);

        for (int k = 0; k < 6;) {
            // here value = lottery.get(k);
            if (value == number) {
                found = true;

            } else {
                found = false;
            }

            if (found == true) {
                number = (int) (Math.random() * 42 + 1);

            } else {
                k++;

            }

        }
        System.out.println("number " + (i + 1) + ": " + number);
        if (found == false) {
            lottery.add(number);
            count[number]++;
            i++;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is so clear. *it says the the Array list is index:1 size: 1*

Comment: n is never incremented, the top for loop with never finish

Comment: It does its just later on, in the code. and k starts at 1, I forgot to change it.

Comment: I've formatted your code as it was hard to read. If youre not using an IDE i would suggest to start using one as it will help a lot as a beginner. I would suggest Netbeans. There is a shortcut to format your code - Alt Shift F. Why does your `for` loops not have the third part (usually `i++` stuff)

Comment: If you want to not add duplicates you can simply just check the arraylist to see if the value is part of it. `lottery.contains(x);`

Answer (score 2):

I assumed `count` is the array you want check
two mistakes I noticed 
value parameter never changed so it will always stay `=0`
and in this code

```
 number = (int) (Math.random() * 42 + 1);
 if (value == number) {
      found = true;
```

number will never be equal to zero 
 so

```
if (found == false) {
    lottery.add(number);
    count[number]++;
    i++;
}
```

will always be executed
and adding new element to lottery will always happen twice in each loop 
and there is no `n++`
so basicaly your big for loop will never end 
and by this code

```
first = (int) (Math.random() * 42 + 1);
```

are you sure count length is exactly 42 because if less it will cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException`
and if more than `42` you are not checking for all elements in it :)
hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

It looks like to me, that you have no way of your for loop ending. You don't have anything that would allow for the increment of the loop to go up, such as i++. Maybe that could solve the problem that you're facing.

Comment: Maybe you should look more closely, because there are both `i++` and `k++`.